# retrieve user path environment variable

Tags: c++, windows, environment-variables, env, getenv

I try to retrieve the path environment variable on Windows. Therefore, I tried

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  char* path = getenv("Path");
  cout << "current path is:" << path << endl;
  cin.get(); // program shall be closed when it's finished
}
```

This works fine and gives me a path. I compared it to my actual path and found out that the path I retrieved by this program is the *system* path. However, I don't want to get the *system* path but rather the *user* path. I tried to change the case of `"Path"` as on my system `"path"` refers to the *user* path variable while `"Path"` refers to the *system* path variable, but `getenv` seems to ignore that. How can I get the value of the *system* path variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getenv("PATH");` It will retrieve the *system* path and *user* path together.

You need to use Windows registry mechanism to find out *user* and *system* path separately. To access them, read the value of `PATH`  from two different positions in the registry:

User variables:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment
```

System variables:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment
```

Comment: Thank you! One question more (I'm curious :) ): What happens if I set the path via `setenv`. Will both paths be changed?

Comment: Nice question, Setting variables by `setenv` will not save them permanently in system and it doesn't matter which of them are changed.